# Why term_id is not indexed in wp_term_taxonomy table?

Tags: database

Every ***category*** or ***tag*** (i.e. electronics) is stored as term in ***`wp_terms`*** table which is indexed with ***`name`*** and ***`slug`***, and its relationship with taxonomy is stored in ***`wp_term_taxonomy`*** table which is indexed as ***`taxonomy`*** and ***`term_taxonomy_id`***.

I can find ***`term_id`*** from ***`wp_terms`*** table using ***`name`*** efficiently because it is indexed with ***`name`***, but then I have to use ***`term_id`*** further to find ***`term_taxonomy_id`*** from ***`wp_term_taxonomy`*** table, but it is indexed as ***`taxonomy`*** but not ***`term_id`***, and then further I'll use ***`term_taxonomy_id`*** to find ***`object_id` (posts)*** from ***`wp_term_relationship`*** table.

***Question is, why `wp_term_taxonomy` table is not indexed with `term_id` which is important in operations like finding posts related to a particular category or tag or anything else?***

Answer (score 1):

A single term can, theoretically, be present in multiple taxonomies (and have a different description in each). That's where term_taxonomy_id comes into play, referencing a single term within a single taxonomy.

In practice, WP tries to avoid that, and will create a term with the same name and a `-2` (iirc) suffix on the slug if a term with the same slug already exists in a different taxonomy.

Comment: But what about frequent operations like getting posts of a particular term! This can only be optimized if wp_term_taxonomy is indexed with term_id which is not. And if repetition is the problem, wp_term_taxonomy is indexed with taxonomy which definitely will be repeated, however repeating term is still the rare case.

Comment: Yes, de-normalizing database schemas can improve speed, but it has other side effects, see [the wikipedia article about normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).